# How do I remove whitespace from a StringList?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am loading a text file (which contains many lines, some containing spaces or tabs) to a StringList. How can I remove whitespace (excluding newlines) from the entire StringList?

Comment: If you remove them, it will be a large single string of the text file. What you want to do with that large string

Comment: ah , i don't need that , there is no way that removing spaces from line to line ? :S

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a crude solution that assumes that tab and space are the only white space characters:

```
tmp := Strings.Text;
tmp := StringReplace(tmp, #9, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
tmp := StringReplace(tmp, #32, '', [rfReplaceAll]);
Strings.Text := txt;
```

Here's a more advanced version that will detect any whitespace:

```
function RemoveWhiteSpace(const s: string): string;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(s));
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(s) do begin
    if not TCharacter.IsWhiteSpace(s[i]) then begin
      inc(j);
      Result[j] := s[i];
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(Result, j);
end;
...
Strings.Text := RemoveWhiteSpace(Strings.Text);
```

You'll need one of the Unicode versions of Delphi and you'll need to use the `Character` unit.

If you are using a non-Unicode version of Delphi then you would replace the if with:

```
if not (s[i] in [#9,#32]) then begin
```

Comment: i am using delphi7 is there any chance that i can get work removewhitspace function in delphi 7 ?

Comment: +1 for preallocating the string (as everyone should do always, but this isn't the case). (I trust you will correct the syntax errors.)

Comment: @david thanks sir it worked great , but u did blunder u used procedure instead of fucntion :)

Comment: @NOP thanks, fixed it now, I just wrote it info the answer box, didn't bother compiling it, hence the two errors! The memory allocation and indexing is water-tight though - that's the bit I was concentrating on!

Comment: @Andreas I loathe code that does `SetLength(a, Length(a)+1)`!

Comment: @David, any decent programmer should.

Comment: In Delphi XE+ recommended using `uses System.Character` `var C:Char;` `for i := 1 to Length(s) do begin C := s[i]; if C.IsWhiteSpace then begin  /// ...etc` because IsWhiteSpace function is deprecated as per the documentation [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Character.IsWhiteSpace)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much text there is you can use the StringReplace() function on the entire text. Im sure this isnt the most efficient way, however should work.

e.g.

```
var tmpString : String;

    Memo1.LoadFromFile(Filename);    
    tmpString := StringReplace(memo1.Text, #9, '',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Then load the tmpString into the stringlist.